# Projectile Motion - $V_f = V_i + at$ - Divide by zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile

If I have a projectile that is thrown at some horizontal velocity at some height, and horizontal acceleration is zero, can't I use the equation $v = v_0 + at$? The problem is when I use it since $v$ will equal $v_0$ (acceleration is zero so velocity won't change) I get $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined and definitely not the answer.

Comment: assume you mean $$v=v_0+at$$

Comment: What equation do you use where the acceleration is in the denominator. I don't understand question as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the distance $s$ something traveled to go from speed $V_i$ to speed $V_f$ use the formula $$s = \frac{V_f^2-V_i^2}{2 a}$$

But this assumes *some acceleration* in order for $V_f \neq V_i$. If the acceleration is zero then use $s = V \Delta t $. You will need to know the time of motion, instead of the beginning and ending speed.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. That is what I was trying to say in my answer below. You have a much better explanation though so I'll accept your answer

Comment: Your answer calculates distance rather than time but it still illustrates the same point that the equation depends on acceleration not being zero.

Comment: Responding to the comments of @Bhaskar I think it's important to state that the startingpoint: $s = \frac{a}{2}.t^2+v.t+s_0$ is valid as long as a is constant, even if  a = 0. Only, if $a=0$, it reduces to $s=v.t$ and if $a\neq 0$, it can be combined with $v = a.t + v_0$ (which is also valid for every constant a, including 0) to write the first equation above.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the vertical component until it h=0, it hits the ground. Use this time t in the horizontal $s=ut+(1/2)at^2$ where a is 0. Because horizontal acceleration is zero.

Comment: I wasn't sure this is "on topic", as you can find examples in many text books. Still you did get an upvote, so someone thinks you are on topic.

Comment: I understand that we can do this, and that's what I usually do, but is there any reason that equation doesn't work for horizontal component on its own. This question is more out of curiosity as to why this equation that should generally work for any situation, doesn't work when used with the horizontal component of a typical projectile motion circumstance.

Comment: The problem isn't bounded in the horizontal direction. If you asked the same  question with a wall at a cetain position and no ground it would be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking about it and I think I realize why that equation didn't work as expected. That equation will always fail to calculate time correctly when acceleration is 0 as it depends on there being a change in velocity between the initial state and the final state. If acceleration is 0 then velocity will always be constant and then time equals all real numbers and the equation will not be able to give a concrete value.